# Which statistical test should I use in my problem? (Permutation, Bootstrap, or some other test)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, paired-data, permutation-test

I have a dataset like this:

H_0: The Test values are randomly generated.

H_A: The Test values are related to the True values.

```
A True:   0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0
A Test:   0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.1
B True:   1,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0
B Test: 0.9, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.8,   0, 0.2
…
```

I would like to test whether the test values are random or is it related to the True set using a statistical method. My hypothesis is to prove the test values are not random and related to the True set. The True and Test are paired in position, and A, B, C … are having different lengths. I have been suggested to use a permutation test, but I am not sure whether it is correct to use it and how to apply it in my problem.

Edit: The test values are probabilities generated by machine learning models, and can be transformed into 0/1 by a threshold of 0.5. A and B themselves are sequence time points of patients, where 0 means normal and 1 means high blood pressure. I would like to test if the model predictions are related to the events or it is just random.

Comment: Can you give us some context about the problem? What do these numbers represent? Are the true labels outcomes, either 0 or 1, and the test values are probabilities? You want to perform such a test for each group A, B, ... separately?

Comment: It is somewhat suspicious that the "Test" values are continuous (probabilities?) and the "True" values are only binary. Can you please explain hte reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: Do you have access to the actual blood pressure reading? Blood pressure is a continuous scale and so a lot of information can be discarded when it is encoded as a binary category.

Comment: @MichaelLew Sadly no, but actually label 1 means it had exceeded the normal high blood pressure range

Comment: Have you already decided that Test can be converted to a binary outcome with a threshold of 0.5 ?  Or would you like to determine this threshold value ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico I would like to reject the null hypothesis that the Test values are not related to the True values, instead of finding the threshold.

Comment: A simple way to test "not related" in this case would be to use correlation. Doing so by permutation test isn't a bad idea considering the distribution of the sample data you present.  It's not clear to me if the analysis would need to take into consideration the fact that observations are grouped by A, B, and so on.  ... Likely, you will be interested not only in the results of the hypothesis test, but in the size of the effect (how well correlated are the two sets of data). ...  Depending on what you want to know, I could see a different analysis, like logistic regression.

Comment: Also, if you are using the 0.5 threshold to convert Test to True, you might consider a confusion matrix to determine how often this conversion makes the correct determination.

Comment: @SalMangiafico is correlation a reasonable test on my dataset? I think the analysis doesn't necessarily treat it by group A,B,... I can concatenate the observations if needed.

Comment: Are there reasons to believe that observations within groups are dependent, e.g., by belonging to the same patient? Are there reasons to believe that the relation between test and true is different in different groups?

Comment: @KaKaOi , I don't know how to answer that question, because I don't know what the groups A, and B mean...  It may make sense to pool all observations, or it may make sense to do something like a logistic regression model with True as the dependent variable and Test and Group as independent variables.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Observations within groups should have some relationship because they belong to the same person. The test are predicted values, so they may be different from the true values, not necessarily by group.

Comment: @SalMangiafico A and B stand for different patients' reading